# I'm not able to use awsume even after installation in WSL

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am using WSL in windows 10. I want to use awsume in wsl-ubuntu.
The installation was done using pip.
But the awsume command give the following error:

```
Warning: the awsume shell script is not being sourced, please use awsume-configure to install the alias
/mnt/c/Users/My Name/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Scripts/awsume: line 8: awsumepy: command not found
/mnt/c/Users/My Name/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Scripts/awsume: line 183: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script
```

I've configured aws in wsl again. I guess the .aws directory in wsl points to .aws in windows. But after installing aws-cli in wsl-ubuntu again, the local installation points to /usr/local/bin/aws

Tried using `hash awsume` to fix the issue, but it didn't work
Any other fixes